# jQuery Datatables filter Column containing dropdowns on text not value.

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using jQuery plugin DataTables for displaying the data from database. Columns have different control type. One of the column say it as COLUMN has select box as control type.
I have also used the filter, pagination features provided by DataTables. Filter on COLUMN filters the datat based on the values in column.

Is there any way to filter data on the text displayed in the box i.e. option's text.

```
self.dummyDataTable = FIT.component.DataTable.init({
        renderTo: 'dummy-index-table',
        id: 'dvmyInputDataGrid',
        data: data[0],
        deferRender: true,
        perPage: 10,
        paging: true,
        scrollY: "200px",
        sScrollX: "200px",
        height: ($(window).height()) * (0.7),
        scroller: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        searchable: true,
        showFilters: true,
        sortable: false,
        aaSorting: [],

        columns: Columns,
        select: {
            style: 'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
    });
```

For ex:

```
<select>
        <option value="0">--- Select Officer---</option>
        <option value="1">Sam</option>
        <option value="2">Brad</option>
        <option value="3">Nicholas</option>
        <option value="4">John</option>
</select>
```

when i set **filter** as true . for this particular select box column it shows list of "Value" attribute in filter box on top of the column like 1,2,3..

A user might get confused between text in the cells and values in the filter box of which user is totally unaware.
Is there any way to filter on the basis of texts i.e Sam, Brad, Nicholas, John.

I have added the code relevant to filtering and searching.

Comment: create a example link so that we can check your problem and rectify it

Comment: Since the data is coming for database and also all the columns are dynamically generated with their control type information coming from dataabase so i will need to create an example with static data.
Meanwhile is there any specific thing you want clarification for?

Answer (score 0):

If I undertand you. You can create the select option with the value of the text you want to search, like:

```
...
<select id="select_name">
    <option value="0">--- Select Officer---</option>
    <option value="Sam">Sam</option>
    <option value="Brad">Brad</option>
    <option value="Nicholas">Nicholas</option>
    <option value="John">John</option>
</select>
...
```

And then add a on change event on select to search in the datatable, like:

```
$('select#select_name').change(function(){
    self.dummyDataTable.columns( <# column> ).search( this.value ).draw();
});
```

Where <# column> is the number of the column you want to search.

Comment: Thanks for quick response @inye
Datatables has a integrated feature for filtering. So what it does is that whatever is the control type of that column, it will put a filter with same control type on the top of the column. Suppose if a column has a control type of text box, filter box will be of the type text box, if it is of select box then filter box will be of the type select box.